# Qt creator throws permission error on project (files owned by me) within directory of root

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

I have recently changed to arch linux from ubuntu and copied my qt project to my home directory,

Whenever I open the project with qt creator, it gives me permission error and says that it cannot write any file.

```
khajvaharch[~/convQML]
[19:24]:ls -l
total 88
-rw-rw-rw- 1 khvah root   3400 Aug 29 08:53 convQML64.png
-rw-rw-rw- 1 khvah root   4945 Aug 29 08:53 convQML80.png
-rw-rw-rw- 1 khvah root    217 Aug 29 08:53 convQML.desktop
-rw-rw-rw- 1 khvah root    282 Aug 29 08:53 convQML_harmattan.desktop
-rw-rw-rw- 1 khvah root    784 Aug 29 18:53 convQML.pro
-rw-rw-rw- 1 khvah root  17523 Sep  1 13:33 convQML.pro.user
-rw-rw-rw- 1 khvah root  17917 Sep  1 13:33 convQML.pro.user.37a898c
drwxr-xrwx 2 khvah root   4096 Aug 29 10:37 icons
-rw-rw-rw- 1 khvah users   367 Sep  2 19:13 main.cpp
-rw-rw-rw- 1 khvah root     54 Aug 29 19:02 mainwindow.cpp
-rw-rw-rw- 1 khvah root    204 Aug 29 19:02 mainwindow.h
drwxr-xrwx 3 khvah root   4096 Aug 29 08:53 qml
drwxr-xrwx 2 khvah root   4096 Aug 29 08:53 qtquick2applicationviewer
```

The directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  root      4096 Sep  1 13:33 convQML
```

As you see, all the files are owned my me and I open qt creator from my account. I can edit every file from this project with other text-editors but not with qt creator.

My guess at first was that I was running qt creator not as khvah but I am logged in with that accout and I start the application from that account

So, what can be my problem?

Comment: What are the permission on the directory (not on the files, but on the dir)?

Comment: @Hennes ok, that was the problem, it belonged to root but why would it be the case? Why can I edit my files with other text-editors and but with creator and it's not like the project file is the directory... Please, write the explanation as an answer, so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably that the other editors changed the existing files (which you are allowed to read and write to), but that QT creator read the old content and then tried to create a **new** file with the changed contents. That only works if you have permissions to create new files in that directory.